# how to Parse a local XML file in android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

I'm working on an android project, and I can't parse a local file (raw/file.xml). I've tried few advices that I've found on internet but in vain.
It works when i try parsing a file in net (using URL Class...) but when i try with a local file program doesn't work !!! Please I need Help .
(I use Sax as XML Parser)

I replace the line URL `sourceUrl = new URL ("example.com/w...";);` with `InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example));`

and the line `xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));` with `xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));`

Comment: It doesn't work? ellaborate it, what happens.

Comment: I replace the line 
URL sourceUrl = new URL ("http://www.example.com/w...");
with          
 InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example));
 
 and the line 
 xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

with 
xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));

Comment: @user1514941, Your comment is unreadable, please edit your question adding those lines of code, or a whole application code if possible.

Comment: Ok I've tried changing command line :
""URL sourceUrl = new URL ("http://www.example.com/w.xml");""
with          
""InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example));""
and the line 
""xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));""
with this
""xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));""
I would be grateful if you can help me !! 
I apologize for my english

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can put the xml file path here and keep parsing the inner nodes usiln self running loop. Save the values in arrays accordingly for each node..

    NodeList eNodeList = null;
eNodeList = Utils.getXMLFromFilePath(your.xml", "firstNOdeNAme", eNodeList);
getElementsByNodelist(eNodeList)


    private static getElementsByNodelist(Nodelist nodelist)
{
    if(nodelist!=null)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<nodelist.getLength();i++)
        {
            Element element = (Element) nodelist.item(i);
            String id=getTextValue(element, "id");
            //For attribute value
            element.getAttribute("attributename");
            // if u want to parse tjis element again 
            NodeList l=element.getElementsByTagName("innerTag");
            // self loop
            getElementsByNodelist(l);
        }
    }

}

public static String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
    String textVal = "";
    NodeList nl = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        Element el = (Element)nl.item(0);
        if(el.getFirstChild()!=null)    
        {
            textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
    }
    return textVal;
}
```